# Why webapi binder translates first two letters to lowercase?

Tags: entity-framework, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

Using EF and OData in webapi.

```
return dataContext.Items
```

Item model has field `URDecisionDate`, when items converted to json my expectation to see field `uRDecisionDate` - first letter was translated to lowercase, however in reality I has `urDecisionDate`. Does somebody know why?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've enabled `ODataConventionModelBuilder::EnableLowerCamelCase();`.

I'm not sure whether it's a "standard" that we should convert `URDecisionDate` to `uRDecisionDate` (or `urDecisionDate`). But if you like to have a control over the property name, you could always use **`[DataContract]`** as well as **`[DataMember]`** to control the property name when serializing some object to `JSON`/`XML`/etc.

```
[DataContract]
public class Item
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "uRDecisionDate")]
    public string URDecisionDate{get;set;}
}
```